# Embedding an animated matplotlib in tk

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, python-embedding

I am fairly new to python and a real beginner to tkinter and matplotlib.
I have the following code which essentially is a testbed for what I eventually want to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import  numpy as np
from  matplotlib import  pyplot as plt
import time

top = 100
plt.ion () # set plot to animated
xdata = []
c = 0
for a in range(0,top):
 xdata.append(a)
 c+=1
ydata =  [ 0 ] *  top * 10
ax1 = plt.axes ()  
c = 0
myfile = open("rdata.txt", "r")
for myline in myfile:
q = myline
ydata[c] = q 
c+=1
c = 0
# Make plot
line, =  plt.plot (ydata[0:60])

myfile = open("rdata.txt", "r")

for p in range(0, top * 10):
for myline in myfile:
      q = int(myline)
      ydata.append (q)
      del  ydata [ 0 ]
      line.set_xdata (np.arange ( len (ydata)))
      line.set_ydata (ydata)   # update the data
      time.sleep(0.01)
      plt.draw () # update the plot 

#   c +=1


file.close(myfile)
```

How can I embed this in tkinter.
I have searched for hours and have come across many suggestions but it seems none of them apply to dynamic plots.
If anyone wants to see the data this program is using I created it with the following code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random

myfile = open("rdata.txt", "w")
myfile.write("100\n")
myfile.write("0\n")
for x in range(2,100):
 q = random.randint(10,90)
 myfile.write(str(q))
 myfile.write("\n")

file.close(myfile)
```

Of course it may just be that I am just not understanding this correctly

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, I added a button that will start animation:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib

matplotlib.use("TKAgg")
import pylab as pl
fig, ax = pl.subplots()
p = 0
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
y = np.sin(x+p)
line, = ax.plot(x, y)
canvas = fig.canvas.get_tk_widget()

from Tkinter import Button

def anim():
    global p
    p += 0.04
    y = np.sin(x+p)
    line.set_data(x, y)
    fig.canvas.draw()
    canvas.after(50, anim)

def go():
    anim()

b = Button(canvas.master, text="go", command=go)
b.pack()
pl.show()
```

Comment: Thanks but this is just the problem I am having. I cannot get it to take the data from the list I generate. No matter what I try it complains. Here are some of the errors:

Comment: File "./anim3.py", line 29, in <module>
    line, = ax.plot(x, y)

    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension                     

If you look at my original code you will see I read a file and fill a list with the values and then the plot is using those values as the y co-ordinate. I cannot find the right way to feed it in

Comment: It works fine if I don't try to embed it in a root window or frame or anything else for that matter. If you paste the code and save it as a python script and use the other script to generate the initial data file, saving it in the same directory, it will work great.