# Embedding a matplotlib animation into a tkinter frame

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib, tkinter, python-embedding

For a project I am working on a simple harmonic motion simulator (How a mass oscillates over time). I have got the data produced correctly and already have a graph produced within a tkinter frame work. At the moment it only shows a static graph where my objective is to display the graph as an animation over time.

So for ease sake I have created a mock up of the programme using the following code:

```
#---------Imports
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as Tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
#---------End of imports

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)        # x-array
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    return line,

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), interval=25, blit=False)
#plt.show() #What I want the object in tkinter to appear as

root = Tk.Tk()

label = ttk.Label(root,text="SHM Simulation").grid(column=0, row=0)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=1)

Tk.mainloop()
```

This code will display the animation that I want in the tkinter frame work when the `plt.show()` is uncommented. I would like to be able to place that animation within the framework of tkinter.

I have also been on the matplotlib website and viewed all of the animation examples and none of them have helped. I have also looked on [Embedding an animated matplotlib in tk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21179971/embedding-an-animated-matplotlib-in-tk) and that has placed the tkinter button within pyplot figure, whereas I would like to place the figure within a tkinter frame.

So just to clarify, I would like to be able to place the animation produced when `plt.show()` is uncommented in a tkinter frame, ie `root = tk()`.

Answer (score 9):

I modified your code:

```
#---------Imports
from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import tkinter as Tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
#---------End of imports

fig = plt.Figure()

x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)        # x-array

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(np.sin(x+i/10.0))  # update the data
    return line,

root = Tk.Tk()

label = Tk.Label(root,text="SHM Simulation").grid(column=0, row=0)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=1)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.sin(x))
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), interval=25, blit=False)

Tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Highlighting the key modifications and reasoning could make this answer even more useful.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the answer of ***user151522*** that didnt  work for me at the first try, i made a few modifications to work in python 3.7:

```
#---------Imports

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

import tkinter as tk
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
#---------End of imports



from tkinter import Frame,Label,Entry,Button


class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()


    def Clear(self):      
        print("clear")
        self.textAmplitude.insert(0, "1.0")
        self.textSpeed.insert(0, "1.0")       


    def Plot(self):
        self.v = float(self.textSpeed.get())
        self.A = float(self.textAmplitude.get())


    def animate(self,i):
        self.line.set_ydata(self.A*np.sin(self.x+self.v*i))  # update the data
        return self.line,


    def init_window(self):



        self.master.title("Use Of FuncAnimation in tkinter based GUI")
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=1)     

        #Create the controls, note use of grid

        self.labelSpeed = Label(self,text="Speed (km/Hr)",width=12)
        self.labelSpeed.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.labelAmplitude = Label(self,text="Amplitude",width=12)
        self.labelAmplitude.grid(row=0,column=2)

        self.textSpeed = Entry(self,width=12)
        self.textSpeed.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.textAmplitude = Entry(self,width=12)
        self.textAmplitude.grid(row=1,column=2)

        self.textAmplitude.insert(0, "1.0")
        self.textSpeed.insert(0, "1.0")
        self.v = 1.0
        self.A = 1.0


        self.buttonPlot = Button(self,text="Plot",command=self.Plot,width=12)        
        self.buttonPlot.grid(row=2,column=1)

        self.buttonClear = Button(self,text="Clear",command=self.Clear,width=12)
        self.buttonClear.grid(row=2,column=2)


        self.buttonClear.bind(lambda e:self.Clear)



        tk.Label(self,text="SHM Simulation").grid(column=0, row=3)

        self.fig = plt.Figure()

        self.x = 20*np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)        # x-array


        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.x, np.sin(self.x))        


        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=4)


        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.animate, np.arange(1, 200), interval=25, blit=False)




root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x400")
app = Window(root)
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer will hopefully be allowed. It is an answer to what I was actually interested in, when I initially found this question, that is, 'Embedding a Matplotlib animation into a tkinter based GUI'.

The code that gave the previous screenshot  has been extended, in this code the canvas has been placed inside a class definition, together with some code for two command buttons, these buttons don't actually do "anything" but the structure is there for possible further development.

The following screenshot was produced with the aid of the extended code

[A screenshot of the SHM animation running from within a tkinter based GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9nJTB.jpg)

The extended code used for the above screenshot  is given below.

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Frame,Label,Entry,Button
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master = None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()


    def Clear(self):
        x=0

#    def Plot(self):
#        x=0

    def init_window(self):


        def animate(i):
           self.line.set_ydata(np.sin(self.x+i/10.0))  # update the data
           return self.line,

        self.master.title("Use Of FuncAnimation in tkinter based GUI")
        self.pack(fill='both', expand=1)     

#Create the controls, note use of grid

        self.labelSpeed = Label(self,text="Speed (km/Hr)",width=12)
        self.labelSpeed.grid(row=0,column=1)
        self.labelAmplitude = Label(self,text="Amplitude",width=12)
        self.labelAmplitude.grid(row=0,column=2)

        self.textSpeed = Entry(self,width=12)
        self.textSpeed.grid(row=1,column=1)
        self.textAmplitude = Entry(self,width=12)
        self.textAmplitude.grid(row=1,column=2)


#        self.buttonPlot = Button(self,text="Plot",command=self.Plot,width=12)
        self.buttonPlot = Button(self,text="Plot",width=12)
        self.buttonPlot.grid(row=2,column=1)
        self.buttonClear = Button(self,text="Clear",command=self.Clear,width=12)
        self.buttonClear.grid(row=2,column=2)

#        self.buttonClear.bind(lambda e:self.Plot)
        self.buttonClear.bind(lambda e:self.Clear)



        tk.Label(self,text="SHM Simulation").grid(column=0, row=3)

        self.fig = plt.Figure()

        self.x = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.01)        # x-array


        self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.x, np.sin(self.x))        


        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(column=0,row=4)


        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, animate, np.arange(1, 200), interval=25, blit=False)




root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("700x400")
app = Window(root)
tk.mainloop()
```