# Speed up plotting with matplotlib in kivy

Tags: python, matplotlib, kivy, matplotlib-animation

I'm trying to optimize the plotting in matplotlib in real time. I've tried to implement through `plt.plot` and `plt.figure`. In the case of `plt.plot`, the graph was updated due to return `FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())`, this method copes disgustingly, after 100 points, the fps drops from 30 to 10. With `plt.figure` (using `plt.canvas.draw`), the situation somewhat better, the initial fps is about 70...80, it drops to 15 after about 500...600 points.

```py
import matplotlib
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from garden_matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label

import matplotlib.animation as animation

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------#

n = 0
x = 0
y = 0
s=0
lst = [[x],
       [y]]
plt_limit_x=200
plt_limit_y=1000
fig=plt.figure()
#--------------------------------MENUSCREEN------------------_-------------#
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass
    box = ObjectProperty(None)
    
#------------------------------------PLOT----------------------------------#
class MyFigure(FigureCanvasKivyAgg): #Plot
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global fig
        global x
        global y
        y=x+x
        x+=1
        lst[0].append(x)
        lst[1].append(y)
        self.ax=fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.line = self.ax.plot(lst[0], lst[1])
        super(MyFigure, self).__init__(fig, **kwargs)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        
    def start_updating(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/30)

    def stop_updating(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.Update)

    def Update(self, *args):
        global fig, x, y, lst, n
        self.line.clear()
        n=n+1
        y=x+x
        x+=1
        lst[0].append(x)
        lst[1].append(y)
        self.line = self.ax.plot(lst[0], lst[1], color='black')
        
        return fig.canvas.draw()  

#------------------------------------MAINAPP----------------------------------#
class MainApp(MDApp):
     
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        return sm

    def on_start(self):
        self.fps_monitor_start()   

#---------------------------------END-------------------------------------#
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

I decided to try to implement matplotlib.animation, following the example I wrote plt.show() derivation and everything works fine.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
x=0
y=0
data = ([x],[y])
def update_line(*args, **kwargs):
    global x
    global y
    
    x=x+1
    y=y+2
    data[0].append(x)
    data[1].append(y)
    l.set_data(data)
    #print (l)
    return l,

fig1 = plt.figure()


    
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')
plt.xlim(0, 10000)
plt.ylim(0, 10000)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.title('test')
line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig1, update_line, 10000, fargs=(data, l),
    interval=1, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

But when I try to translate it into kivy, the graph does not want to be updated, there is an assumption that the problem is in the **init** method, but I don’t know how to implement the program without it.

```
import matplotlib
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from garden_matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label

import matplotlib.animation as animation

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------#


n = 0
x = 0
y = 0
s=0
lst = [[x],
       [y]]
fig=plt.figure()
data = ([x],[y])
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')

#--------------------------------MENUSCREEN------------------_-------------#

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass
    box = ObjectProperty(None)
    

#------------------------------------PLOT----------------------------------#

class MyFigure(FigureCanvasKivyAgg):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        global l
        plt.xlim(0, 10000)
        plt.ylim(0, 10000)
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.title('test')
        super(MyFigure, self).__init__(fig, **kwargs)
        
    def start_updating(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/30)

    def stop_updating(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.Update)

    def Update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global x, y, l #data
        x=x+1
        y=y+2
        data[0].append(x)
        data[1].append(y)
        #print (data)
        l.set_data(data)
        print (l)
        return l,
    line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                                       Update,
                                       10000,
                                       fargs=(data, l),
                                       interval=1,
                                       blit=True)     

    fig.canvas.draw()

#------------------------------------MAINAPP----------------------------------#
class MainApp(MDApp):
     
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        return sm

    def on_start(self):
        self.fps_monitor_start()   
#---------------------------------END-------------------------------------#
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Please help optimize the program. It might be possible to do this with fig.canvas.draw(). But in the ideal case, one would like to use matplotlib.animation.

UPD. I completely forgot, here is the main.kv file code

```
<Manager>:
    transition: SlideTransition()
    MenuScreen:
        name: 'MenuScreen'

<MenuScreen>:
    box: box
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        GridLayout:
            cols: 1
            size_hint: .2, 1
            Button:
                text: 'Start measurement'
                on_press: myfig.start_updating()
            Button:
                text: 'Stop measurement'
                on_press: myfig.stop_updating()
            Button:
                text: 'Quit'
                on_press: app.root_window.close ()
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: .8, 1
            id:box
            MyFigure:
                id:myfig
```

UPD. Found a similar issue using Tkinter [Embedding a matplotlib animation into a tkinter frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21197728/21889638), after converting the code to add the init_plot function,

```
import matplotlib
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from garden_matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label

import matplotlib.animation as animation

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------#


n = 0
x = 0
y = 0
s=0
lst = [[x],
       [y]]
fig=plt.figure()
data = ([x],[y])
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')

#--------------------------------MENUSCREEN------------------_-------------#

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass
    box = ObjectProperty(None)
    

#------------------------------------PLOT----------------------------------#

class MyFigure(FigureCanvasKivyAgg):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyFigure, self).__init__(fig, **kwargs)
        self.init_plot()
        
    def start_updating(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/30)

    def stop_updating(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.Update)
   

#fig.canvas.draw()
    

    def Update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global x, y, l #data
        x=x+1
        y=y+2
        data[0].append(x)
        data[1].append(y)
        #print (data)
        l.set_data(data)
        print (l)
        return l,

    def init_plot(self):
        global fig
        global l
        plt.xlim(0, 10000)
        plt.ylim(0, 10000)
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.title('test')
        line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                                        self.Update,
                                        10000,
                                        fargs=(data, l),
                                        interval=1,
                                        blit=True)  
#------------------------------------MAINAPP----------------------------------#
class MainApp(MDApp):
     
    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
        return sm

    def on_start(self):
        self.fps_monitor_start()   
#---------------------------------END-------------------------------------#
if __name__=='__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

I got the following error:

```
File "C:\Python\Stackoverflow question\13.05.2023\garden_matplotlib\backend_kivy.py", line 1078, in _timer_set_interval
     if self._timer is not None:
 AttributeError: 'TimerKivy' object has no attribute '_timer'. Did you mean: '_on_timer'?
```

If I put `line_ani` in the `build` function I get a similar error.

I tried to use matplotlib.animation in simple Kivy project but got the same error too

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.clock import Clock
import matplotlib.animation as animation

n = 0
x = 0
y = 0
s=0
lst = [[x],
       [y]]
fig=plt.figure()
data = ([x],[y])
l, = plt.plot([], [], 'r-')
canvas = FigureCanvasKivyAgg(fig)

class MainApp(App):

    def init_plot(self):
        global fig, l
        plt.xlim(0, 10000)
        plt.ylim(0, 10000)
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.title('test')


    def on_press_button(self, instance):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, 1/30)

    def Update(self, *args, **kwargs):
        global x, y, l #data
        x=x+1
        y=y+2
        data[0].append(x)
        data[1].append(y)
        #print (data)
        l.set_data(data)
        print (l)
        return l,
    
    def build(self):
        main_layout = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        grid_layout=GridLayout(cols=1,
                               row_force_default=True,
                               row_default_height=100,
                               size_hint=(.2,1)
                               )
        main_layout.add_widget(grid_layout)
        grid_layout.add_widget(Label(text='Hello from Kivy'))

        button1=grid_layout.add_widget(Button(text='Hello 1', on_press=self.on_press_button))
        global canvas
        main_layout.add_widget(canvas)

        print ('build called')
        return main_layout
    line_ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,
                                        Update,
                                        10000,
                                        fargs=(data, l),
                                        interval=1,
                                        blit=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MainApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved, the point was that with each update, new graphs were built. I figured it out using the `print (self.ax.get_lines())`. Actually here is the solution. Instead of building a new plot in a loop (i mean `schedule_interval`) with `self.line = self.ax.plot(lst[0], lst[1], color='black')`, we set  in `__init__` ,`self.line = self.ax.plot (lst[0], lst[1], color='black')`. Note that a comma is placed after `line`. This is necessary to return a list of `Line2D` objects. After that, we draw the graph in a loop as in the first option: `fig.canvas.draw()`. As a result, a stable 60 fps was obtained.

The problem with the bug below is still open. For me it looks like there is no way to work in `Kivy` with `matplotlib.animation`.

```
File "C:\Python\Stackoverflow question\13.05.2023\garden_matplotlib\backend_kivy.py", line 1078, in _timer_set_interval
     if self._timer is not None:
 AttributeError: 'TimerKivy' object has no attribute '_timer'. Did you mean: '_on_timer'?
```

UPD.The draw method `fig.canvas.draw_idle()` works faster in my case, stabe 70 FPS.

UPD. What do we know in the end?

- We can't use the `clear()`, `cla()` or `clf()` methods in a loop, because they are extremely slow.
- `plt.plot` with `FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf())` is slow.
- We need to use `FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.fig())`.
- If we use the `draw()` method, it returns the entire graph each time, and each time a new line in each cycle.
- The solution is to use `self.ax=fig.add_subplot()` and `self.line,= self.ax.plot()` with a comma in the `__init__` function. To update the graph, we add data in each cycle using `self.line.set_data([],[])`.
- To draw the graph at the end of the loop, use `fig.canvas.draw_idle()`, which is somewhat faster (about 10-20%) than `fig.canvas.draw()`.